# Table Cell seems to lose binding when the table is pulled up

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an issue with a Xamarin IOS project using MVVMCross.  There is a MvxTableViewController which displays a variety of MvxTableViewCells. When the user touches inside a text field in a cell and then pulls the table view controller up, the data in the focused cell disappears.  As far as I can tell, there is no application code executing after this gesture.

I've attached screens showing the data before, during and after the screen is pulled up.  There are no messages written to the console during this event.

Any idea where I should Look for this issue?
[image: Here is the screen before doing anything with it]

[image: Here is the screen being pulled up]

[image: Here is the screen after the gesture. Notice the data in the text field is gone, the label is gone and the textfield is disabled (this value is also a binding).]

**Update**

Here is the code used to bind the values in the cell's constructor.  There's a bit more than just binding going on, but I included it all in case it is impacting the issue.

Thanks!

```
public BaseComponentCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)        
{

this.DelayBind (() => {

    ComponentValueTextField.ShouldReturn += (textField) => {
        textField.ResignFirstResponder ();

        var component = (BaseComponent)DataContext;

        if(component.DoneEditingCommand!=null){

            component.DoneEditingCommand.Execute(null);

        }

        return true;

     };

    var myComponent = (BaseComponent)DataContext;
    if (myComponent.DisplayNumberPadKeyboard)
    {
        ComponentValueTextField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
    }


    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<BaseComponentCell, BaseComponent> ();

    set.Bind(ComponentNameLabel).To(c=>c.ComponentName);

    set.Bind(ComponentValueTextField).To(c=>c.ComponentValue);
    set.Bind(ComponentValueTextField).For(f => f.Enabled).To(c => c.IsEnabled);
    set.Bind(this).For(bc=>bc.IsSecure).To(c=>c.IsSecure);

    set.Apply();



});
```

}

Comment: How is that ItemNumber cell bound? It might be a general mvx bug caused by the code we run when a cell is scrolled off screen but would to see repro code to be sure. Certainly nothing I've seen reported before.

Comment: (this `CellDisplayingEnded` line is the only one I can think of -  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxBaseTableViewSource.cs#L109. Reading the docs it shouldn't cause this type of problem - but maybe we've read them wrong)

Comment: Thanks Stuart!  I'll try to override that method and see if I can figure out what's going on.  I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: I overrode the CellDisplayingEnded method in the TableViewSource and set a breakpoint.  The breakpoint is never hit though.  I was able to workaround the issue by disabling scrolling on this particular screen.    If you can think of anything else to look at, I'd be happy to try.  I also noticed while I touch the cell, the information is displayed.  It disappears as soon as I let go.

Comment: I can't think of anything else - can you repro this in a simple sample?

Comment: I should be able to reproduce it.  This week is going to be crazy so it might take a couple days to pull it together.